# Как запустить цикл foreach внутри printf, которая также выводится в цикле foreach?

Tags: php, foreach, printf

Здравствуйте! Внутри цикла `foreach` выводится блок статьи функцией `printf()`.

Необходимо запустить вывод тегов внутри `printf()`. Теги хранятся в отдельной ячейке и разделены "/". То есть нужно сделать что-то подобное:

```
foreach ($pages AS $page) {
  printf(
    /* тут какой-то код html с маркерами "%s", в котором есть некий блок div, где нужно вывести теги, обработанные функцией explode("/", $page["tags"]); */
    foreach ($tags AS $tag) {
      printf("<a href='/search_view.php?submit=&select=tag&query=%s' title='Поиск по тегу'>%s</a>", $tag["0"], $tag["0"]);
    }
    ,
    $page["id"],
    $page["title"] /* и так далее */
  );
}
```

Простым языком - цикл вывел часть html-кода, дошёл до блока с тегами - вывел теги и пошёл выводить html-код дальше. Затем снова, пока в таблице базы данных не закончатся строки, которые нужно выводить. Как-то так.

Comment: не совсем понял, по отдельности нельзя?

    foreach($pages AS $page){
      $tags = explode( "/", $page['tags']);
      $block = "";
      foreach($tags AS $tag){
        $block .= sprintf("<a href=...", $tag[0], $tag[0]);
      }
      // а теперь основной html
      printf(
        "какой-то html, %s место под блок, %s место под title",
        $block,
        $page['id'],
        $page['title']
      );
    }

Comment: @Sergiks тогда нарушится вёрстка. теги должны выводится внутри блока, который также выводится в цикле. Возможно можно сделать как-то иначе, например, вывести теги отдельно и как-то занести их в переменную

Comment: Так идёт вывод сейчас:
foreach ($pages AS $page) { 
printf("
<div class='article_block'>    
    <a href='/view_article.php?id=%s' target='_self' title='%s' class='pre_img'><img src='%s' width='640'></a>
    <div class='tags_block'>%s</div>
    <div class='article_block_name'>
        <p><a href='/magazine/male_articles/view_article.php?id=%s' target='_self'>%s</a></p></div></div>", $page["id"], $page["title"], $page["article_img"], $page["tags"], $page["id"], $page["title"]);
                        }

Comment: Нужно в
<div class='tags_block'>%s</div>
вместо "%s" выводить каждое слово тега в теге <a href"..." class="..."></a>

Comment: Вам @Sergiks правильно подсказал. Никакая вёрстка не нарушится, а если и нарушилась, то изначально кривая была

Comment: @Torawhite, заметьте разницу между операторами `printf()` и `sprintf()`. Именно, как вы написали, в переменную заносится html тегов, а затем уже выводится вместе с остальной разметкой и переменными.

Answer (score 1):

`eval()`, но это очень плохо.

Comment: @ArchDemon не совсем понимаю, как её применить зжесь

Answer (score 0):

Лучше пересобрать, eval, как уже подсказали, но грузить будет лишний раз, да и вообще...

Comment: @Roundik есть же какой-то проверенный способ решения этой проблемы, панацея, так сказать. Все блоги выводят превью статьи блоками, в которых идёт вывод тегов. Как-то же это делается. Можно, конечно, запихать в ячейку теги сразу в <a></a>, но это как-то неправильно.

Comment: @Roundik, @ArchDemon, @Sergiks делал! Разорвал html-код в том месте, где нужно запустить цикл, вывел так:

foreach ($pages as $page){
printf(первая часть html-кода);

$tags = explode("/", $page["tags"]);
foreach ($tags AS $tag) {
echo "<a href='/search_view.php?submit=&select=tag&query=" . $tag . "' title='Поиск по тегу'>" . $tag . "</a>";
}
printf(первая часть html-кода);
}

@Sergiks идея Ваша, спасибо!